# Setting up an AP from C code rock solid

Tags: wifi, access-point, raspberry-pi-os, hostapd

I have to develop a program for RBPi4 with latest Raspberry OS. I'm coding in C because that's what i know for now. After startup the device's first task is to create a WLAN with predefined ssid,  password and working DHCP, but no internet, so no routing is required.

In order to achieve this from my code I'm using the `system` function to call *exactly the same set of commands* that would do the work from cli:

```
#since this code part might be called again later in the program, im seeking to make a guaranteed clean start:
sudo pkill hostapd
sudo pkill dnsmasq
sudo pkill dhclient
sudo pkill wpa_supplicant
sudo ip addr flush dev wlan0

#then come the main commands:
sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.4.4 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo dnsmasq -iwlan0
sudo hostapd -i wlan0 /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf -B
```

My hostapd.conf (taken from [official sample](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hostapd#802.11b.2Fg.2Fn_with_WPA2-PSK_and_CCMP)):

```
interface=wlan0
hw_mode=g
channel=10
ieee80211d=1
country_code=HU
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
ssid=voltieconfig
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=******************
```

If I run the above commands from cli I always get the desired visible WiFi. But **when I run my program right after RBPi's startup the *hostapd* part sometimes fails (and sometimes succeeds)**. I have tried multiple scenarios but couldn't find out what might cause the unpredictable result.

I managed to catch hostapd's result (extended with a `-d` option in this case) in both successful and unsuccessful cases. Comparing the two it seems that the differences start with an `err=-100 Network is down` error:

[image]

Can you please guess/advise what might cause this problem?
(If it's needed, i can happily attach the whole of both dumps, as well as my .c files.)

Comment: Do you know at which point your program is failing, compared to the cli commands you've shown (since you have shown nothing of the program that is failing)

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, my program fails at the last list of command, the hostapd one. 
`char cmd[] = "sudo hostapd -i wlan0 /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf -B";
ret = system(cmd);`

Comment: *last LINE of command; ran out of editing time

Comment: out of interest, if you delay that line in your code, (1 second or maybe more) - is it any more stable?

Comment: @JaromandaX Even a 0.5s delay with `usleep` before the last command seems to have helped! THX! If you write an answer I would happily accept it as correct. Perhaps with some explanation so we can learn a little more from it.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't rely on an arbitrary delay - all too often I've found arbitrary delays in code work until they don't! A preceding command must be "finishing" before what it does actually completes - which command? I don't know - how to wait correctly, again I don't know - the pause is a workaround not a solution in my opinion